# Logic issue on dynamic static Asyncallback - GWT

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, static

Im trying to test the Performance tip of : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/f9FLCEloW-c/3ZelaqGUGTcJ

I have more than 5 different Callbacks with different result object .

how can i creat a dynamic static class in only one static Class :

```
    public class AsyncCallbacks
{
    private static AsyncCallback<?> callback = null;


    private AsyncCallbacks(){

    }


    private AsyncCallback<?> createCallback() {
          if(callback == null) {

              callback = new AsyncCallback(){

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object result)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

              };



          }
          return callback;
        }






}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public class Asyncs implements AsyncCallback<Object> {

  private Dto1 dto1 = null;
  private Dto2 dto2 = null;

  private Object result = null;

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    // failed message
  }

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(Object result) {
    this.result = result;
  }

  public Object getSuccessObject() {
    if (result instanceof Dto1) {
      dto1 = (Dto1) result;
    } else if (result instanceof Dto2) {
      dto2 = (Dto2) result;
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

Comment: like callback.onSucces